# xcopy file and folder from a changing directory

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I have been having 0 files copied message when attempting to Xcopy files.
Note that I managed to do it successfully by specifying an exact source path as shown below:

```
xcopy /y %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\WinXTweak\program1.exe %WINDIR%\
xcopy /y %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\WinXTweak\program2.exe %WINDIR%\
xcopy /y %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\WinXTweak\program3.exe %WINDIR%\
```

Of course, this would only work if the WinXTweak folder is on the desktop. I would like to be able to copy it into a USB drive for instance or any location in my PC and run it. The location of the batch file is inside the WinXTweak folder too. I could not figure out what to do. I tried the ones below but it did fail.

```
xcopy /y program1.exe %WINDIR%\
xcopy /y program2.exe %WINDIR%\
xcopy /y program3.exe %WINDIR%\
```

Thanks all in advance,

Comment: You are using `%WINDIR%` as your target directory. Even if you were to use the more modern replacement for that legacy variable, `%SYSTEMROOT%`, that directory is probably a protected location. What happens when you test it with a different directory? or, the same location but run the script 'as administrator'?

Comment: In your example administrator privileges are required like @Compo said. Other than that, your examples should work but try surrounding the source and destination directories with quotes like `xcopy "<source>" "<destination>" /y`

Comment: For the purpose of performing the command on any valid location, combine with a For /F` loop operating on Dir command like So: `For %%I in ("program1.exe" "program2.exe" "program3.exe") Do For /F "Delims=" %%F in ('dir /b %%I /s') Do xcopy /y "%%~F"  "%Destination%"`

Comment: Based upon the fact you're only copying files and not utilising the various options of [tag:XCopy], I'd suggest that you replace that command with the internal [tag:Copy] command too. e.g. `@For %%G In (1 2 3) Do @Copy /Y "program%%G.exe" "%SystemRoot%" 1>NUL 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your reply. After reading more stuff online, I was able to resolve the issue by using the following code. I am a newbie at this, and there might be a much simpler way this is what I used.

```
@echo off

set source=%~dp0*.exe
set target="%WINDIR%"
xcopy /y "%source%" "%target%"
```

The suggested answers I will take note and learn so I can use it in the future.

Thank you for helping and best regards,

Comment: Aside from the advice you've already been given in the comments, I suggest that you change your `set` commands to use the recommended syntax. Change `set source=%~dp0*.exe`, to `set "source=%~dp0*.exe"`, and `set target="%WINDIR%"`, to `set "target=%WINDIR%"`.